# update profile image functionality is not working while hosting as jar

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Hi I am new to Springboot I was trying to develop a application, One of its functionality is to upload profile Image. It was working fine in STS but when I pack it in jar and hosting it on AWS EC2 envirnment I am getting some error while processing that image

Error:

[image]

handler for profile picture:

```
@PostMapping("/process-contact")
    public String processContact(@ModelAttribute Contact contact, @RequestParam("profileImage") MultipartFile file,
            HttpSession session) {

        try {

            contact.setUser(user);
            user.getContacts().add(contact);
            // processing and uploading photo

            if (file.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("File is empty");
                contact.setImage("contact.png");

            } else {
                
                //Processing Image
                InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream();
                Path paths = Paths.get(new ClassPathResource("/static/img").getFile().getPath()+"/" +file.getOriginalFilename());
                
                Files.copy(inputStream, paths, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                contact.setImage(file.getOriginalFilename());
                
            }
            
            // Success Message
            session.setAttribute("message", new Message("Your contact is added...", "success"));
            
            this.userRepository.save(user);
            System.out.println("Successfully Added");
        } catch (Exception E) {
            E.printStackTrace();

            // Failed message
            session.setAttribute("message", new Message("Something went wrong "+E.getMessage(), "danger"));
        }

        return "normal/add_contact_form";
    }
```

It is working fine in IDE after some research I found way of writing data in jar is diffrent could some please help me how can I implemenr it for jar also.

Thankyou

Comment: What is the actual file location ?

Comment: @JayeshChoudhary  file location where I am hosting it -->   /home/project/contactmanager1.jar

Comment: I am not sure whether we can update a jar file like this or not or I need to store uploaded images in diffrent directory and load that when I need it

Comment: I think it will be better if you store them in a different location. Storing them with Jar deployment is not a good choice either.

Comment: Any reference would be very helpful if you can share.

Comment: Okay, I am giving you answer. Please accept it if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all you need to do is replace this line:

```
Path paths = Paths.get(new ClassPathResource("/static/img").getFile().getPath()+"/" +file.getOriginalFilename());
```

With:

```
Path paths = Paths.get(new FileSystemResource("/static/img").getFile().getPath()+"/" +file.getOriginalFilename());
```

THat will work like charm.

Comment: I appreciate your effort but using this suggestion I am still getting. java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /static/img/dot.jpeg
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:92)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
        at

Comment: I am hosting that jar on ubuntu so may be forward slash(/) and backward slash can cause this error

Comment: Where are you files exactly ? Please provide exact location from Root. Because when you use / forward slash, it maps path from the root directory.

Comment: /home/project/contactmanager1.jar/BOOT-INF/classes/static/img/

Comment: I think you need to change your file upload functionality as well. In that case this code will work fine. Please check file upload and put **ClassPathResource** in the file upload functionality.

Comment: all the functionality I am using is in the above code  Files.copy(inputStream,path,StandardCopyOption) to save image on provided path

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in my last comment, you need to put **FileSystemResource** in the file upload functionality replacing **ClassPathResource**.  So files will be uploaded at the exact location you put as parameter.

Comment: okay, please join the chat.

Comment: can we talk over chat now

Comment: Jayesh I tried replacing all ClassPathResource calls from that functionality but still getting that error    java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /static/img/dot.jpeg at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:92) at

Comment: Please join the chat , I am here.